# How can I use urllib2, regex, and sys to read a specific URL and then return my search and the results?

Tags: python, regex, urllib2, sys

I am in need of some help for an assignment. I need to build a "simple" (according to my teacher) web-scraper that takes a URL as an argument, searches the source code of that URL, and then returns the links within that source code back (anything after href). The example URL my teacher has been having us use is http://citstudent.lanecc.net/tools.shtml. When the program is executed, there should be ten links returned as well as the URL of the website.

Since I am still trying to wrap my head around these concepts, I wasn't sure where to start so I turned to stack overflow and I found a script that -kind of- works. It does what I want it to do, but does not fulfill every requirement:

```
import urllib2
url = "http://citstudent.lanecc.net/tools.shtml"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = page.read().split("</a>")
tag = "<a href=\""
endtag = "\">"
for item in data:
    if "<a href" in item:
            try:
                    ind = item.index(tag)
                    item = item[ind+len(tag):]
                    end = item.index(endtag)
            except: pass
            else:
                     print item[:end]
```

This works because I hard-coded the URL into my code, and because it prints after some href tags. Normally I would say to just guide me through this and to not just give me the code, but I'm having such a shit day and any explanation or example of this has to be better than what we went over in class. Thank you.

Comment: Have you learned `HTMLParser` yet (`html.parser` in Python 3)? It would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Nope, this class is taught exclusively in Python 2.x

Comment: So, have you learned `HTMLParser` yet? That's the Python 2 version.

Comment: No, we have not